# ASP .NET MVC - Should I run a background timer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, timer

I need to do some processing in the background when the website is running. Every 30 minutes I need to run a piece of code that interacts with the database.

Would it be okay to use a timer that executes the code every 30 minutes or is there a better way of doing this? If timer is okay to implement, I'm thinking to implement it in the Application_Start() function in the Global.asax folder.

From what I've read, a timer wouldn't cause performance issues because for the majority of the time it's not actually running any code.

I've been searching but couldn't find anything MVC related. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: How much control do you have over the hosting environment? You can use something like Quartz.NET to implement a job scheduler in your web application, but it might be easier/better to create a console application that you can run via scheduled tasks or a windows service that will sleep and then wake up every X minutes to do whatever you need it to do.

Comment: You have to take into account that IIS recycles the application pool and your application will not be running until a new request is made. If your timer can check that, it's OK to use it, otherwise I would go for a Windows service.

Comment: Ah, so you think having a separate program like a service to do the job should work. Not sure if it is worth making a completely new helper service for it though, reason being this piece of is not very complex and only involves updating some (around 1000) integers in a database.

Comment: @danradu but after one (first) request is made, it should be okay? Or not?

Comment: It would only be "ok" if your application is able to check something stateful (like a file or db value) on every run - i.e. it's not really a timer, or you're creating a new timer with each request. If it's important that the data is updated with any precision, then a service is better. For example, if your application stopped receiving traffic for 10 minutes, could that much of a delay be a problem?

Comment: Yes, providing the timer restarts and does the work that is pending. Start with a timer and monitor the testing environment (logs, performance counters etc.). If you see any critical issue, or if the work gets too complex, change it to a Windows service.

Comment: Thanks guys for the good suggestions. I am looking into services now, I've been a bit scared to learn it but I need it now so here we go! I've decided that a web service will be best just because I want better stability as my functions grow more complex.

Comment: I know that this is an old post but for future information I suggest you to take a look on this article http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 8):

If you are are really set on building it into asp.net take a look at Haacked's article 
[The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx).

He outlines the dangers and some ways you can combat them, otherwise as others suggested a service/schedule task is a better solution.

Alternatively if you go down the windows service route take a look at [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) its a framework that lets you easily run services as console apps in development while still allowing them to be easily installed on the server