# Checking time continuously

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, loops, web-applications, time

I am writing a simple app in ASP.NET MVC 4. I've researched my issue to no result.

What I need is basic thing. I have got events in the database, which have their deadline. How do I make the application mark them as finished when the deadline is over? I suppose, the app should be checking every deadline all the time and when the time matches a deadline, it changes the event's status.

I'm not asking for a solution or anything, just a nod in which direction should I go or where should I look.

Comment: Why do you even need to change the event status? The deadline *is* the status/criteria. From what you listed, there is not much reason you need to check status instead of just check deadline. If you still need status, it could be for other things. So maybe sometimes you need to check status AND deadline.

Comment: Yea, I need the status for a lot of other things. I just simplified my problem to a minimum information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a few solutions:

1) if you have access to the server where application is hosted - you can create windows service that would check states of events

2) you can create mvc timer job - check this out: [ASP .NET MVC - Should I run a background timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842208/asp-net-mvc-should-i-run-a-background-timer)

3) I'm not sure about it since I'm not SQL Pro - but I belive that it's possible to do it on DB side.

Comment: @ArthurFromLatvia #3 makes most sense. #1 has use, but seems overkill here. and #2... just shouldn't do... that is what #1 is for.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to generate the status whenever you read from the database.  E.g. something like:

```
SELECT
...
CASE WHEN GETUTCDATE() < DeadLineUtc AND Status = "ACTIVE" THEN "EXPIRED"
ELSE Status
END AS Status
...
FROM ...
```